# looping through specifc set of items

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have to create an HTML table dynamically following this condition..The number of columns should be generated dynamically which in our case we will assume 2.So I have a list of items that I have to fill in this table with the items filling in the column as they are generated.The code is not behaving correctly and also not including the last item.Can someone guide me for an easy way to do it.

```
List<NItem> item = new List<NItem>();   

StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    build.Append("<table>");


    for (int q = 0; q < item.Count; q++)
    {
        build.Append("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {               

            build.Append("<td>");
            build.Append(string.Format("<a title= \"{0}\" href=\"{1}\" target=\"_blank\">{2}</a> ", item[i].ToolTip, item[i].Link, item[i].LinkDescription));
            build.Append("</td>");




        }
        build.Append("</tr>");
    }
    build.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: Building Html/xml by hand is not recommended

Comment: I suggest posting this on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). It is off-topic here.

Comment: can we take the c# code aspect of this and work on that .

Comment: What does "not working correctly" mean?

Comment: You've got HTML injection there. Encode the string that you insert. Also, it looks like code is correct. The problem is probably somewhere else.; Did you check the output and manually verify it? Did you find errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the ideal way to accomplish your goal, but I believe this will fix your code. The second loop was just adding the first and second items over and over again.

```
List<NItem> item = new List<NItem>();   

StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
build.Append("<table>");

// Increment the counter by the number of columns
for (int q = 0; q < item.Count; q += columns)
{
    build.Append("<tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {               
        build.Append("<td>");

        if (q + i < item.Count)
        {
            // Grab the item for this column by adding the column index to the item index that we started with
            var currentItem = item[q + i];
            build.Append(string.Format("<a title= \"{0}\" href=\"{1}\" target=\"_blank\">{2}</a> ", currentItem.ToolTip, currentItem.Link, currentItem.LinkDescription));
        }

        build.Append("</td>");
    }
    build.Append("</tr>");
}

build.Append("</table>");
```